# Display modal view controller from AppDelegate every time app is opened

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

I have an app that I need to display a pin/login screen every time the app is open.  My plan is to do this from the AppDelegate. I've been trying to piece together how to do this, but I'm stuck on two pieces.

My app is a tab view controller, so I'm having trouble determining which controller I need to present from.

I tried this to get the root controller:
`let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController` but it is nil . I believe this is because the tab controller isn't embedded in a navigation controller, though both of the controllers in it are.

So my two questions boil down to:

1. If I put the code into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions does that open every time the app is opened?
2. How can I get the root controller view to show the modal from since it is a TabViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Regarding how to know the index you can cast the rootVC as a tabBarController and ask it for the current index (`selectedIndex`) like this

```
let currentIndex = rootTab.selectedIndex
```

2- You can get rootVC as

```
if let rootTab = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
```

you can show it when app becomes active ( in `applicationDidBecomeActive` )  delegate method

to get the VC

```
let vc = rootTab.viewControllers[rootTab.selectedIndex]
```

Comment: Using that I get a nil value for `rootTab.tabBar.selectedItem`

Comment: Last question.  That gives me the index, but I can't figure out how to return that specific controller.  I see how to set, remove and add, but not return the controller at that index.

Comment: Thank you, I did try that initially , but misread the error it gave me and thought it was wrong.  That did work.